# How to sequentially play chunks of videos in Exoplayer

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, exoplayer

I'm trying to develop an Android app that reads a video coming from either the server or other peers that have the video. For this usecase I have to split my videos into smaller pieces to optimize transfer times and each piece can be provided by either the central server or another peer.

I would like to know if exoplayer is able to read a sequence of video pieces without interruption ?
I am free to do whatever I want in the splitting process e.g. split the video with linux command `split`.

Answer (score 2):

Most adaptive bit rate streaming formats work something like your description - they spit the video into multiple chunks and the video player requests them one at a time. Examples of adaptive rate streaming protocols are HLS, MPEG-DASH, SmoothStreaming.

It is possible to have the url for the next 'chunk' of video route to a 'central' server which could proxy the request to another 'peer', if this would meet your needs.

Its worth noting that many videos are delivered via CDN's which might interfere with your desired approach (or alternatively might actually match what you want, depending on what your underlying requirements are) so you may want to check this also.

**Update**

Assuming you mean that some chunks will come from the server and some chunks from peer devices on the network, then the above server proxy method would not work.

One way you could do this would be to have all the chunks delivered to the device from whatever source is best for each chunk, and then put them together as you require on the device and stream the result from 'localhost' on your device to the player.

This sounds like a huge amount of overhead and something that would never work but I believe it is actually a technique used in some apps to convert from one streaming format to another (can't provide example - sorry...).

One example of a 'localhost' server on Android that might be useful to look at is:

- http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/android-web-server

An alternative, if you were to use HTML5 inside a web page on the device you could use the Media Source Extension mechanism to load the video chunks from the different sources before passing them to the player. This does require Chrome at this point rather than the standard Android browser as the latter does not support the MSE extension at the time of writing.

In all these approaches you obviously need to make sure you load enough in advance to keep the video pipeline and buffer full, to avoid pauses.

Comment: I am aware of streaming techniques you described me in your answer. However, I am in control of everything, from the server until the client side application, and thus I will not use any CDN.

I am just wondering if ExoPlayer enable us to manually set an array of video chunks to be read one after another just like it was one single video. It is important to me that the video is splitted into multiple parts (either into pieces of the raw file or into smaller videos) because I want to choose which part are to be delivered by my server and which ones have to be exchanged peer to peer.

Comment: Ah ok - I think you mean peer devices rather than peer servers? I've updated the answer based on this.

Comment: I have just read your update. Thanks a lot, but actually the device to device part will be handled by another guy who told me he is already able to recover the parts of the file from either the server or from a peer device.  My only job is to reorder the chunks recovered and to provide them to a media player of my choice to be read continuously one after another.   
In other words I am not in charge for the data transfers but only for their exploitation. Again I am sorry if I am hard to understand because I am not a native english speaker.